Teaching students how to check the validity of their proofs
The question Teaching students to find and correct their own errors and its answers address mainly calculation problems of the types typically found in secondary school and the lower levels of undergraduate mathematics. What tips do you have for students to check the validity of their proofs, apart from showing them to a more experienced mathematician, and what approaches can we use to help them spot mistakes and errors, and then correct them?

Also of interest: Taxonomy of bad proofs

I would start by making mistakes in your lessons https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-handle-the-situation-when-you-made-a-stupid-mistake-in-front-of-the-class/1462#1462 it is a valuable lesson for the students that if you need to check things as you go along, then it is a valuable skill for them to learn.  Checking as you go (rather than at the end) also limits how far an error can propagate before being corrected.

Frankly, anyone who is unable to check the validity of his/her own proof (excluding careless mistakes) simply does NOT understand what a genuine proof really is. Modern mathematics is based on FOL (first-order logic), and one must at least know a complete deductive system for FOL to be able to truly understand what a rigorous proof is. Informal proofs are nothing more than informal proofs. Once you know how to use a deductive system, it's trivial to check your own proof; just check that you are following the rules!!!

@user21820 +1 Some kind of automated proof-checker that will verify each line of proof as it is entered may be useful in this regard.

@DanChristensen, I see you've written such a proof checker.

@JW Yes, but there are many alternatives.

@user21820: Your comment seems to suggest that we should use a complete deductive system for FOL to teach proofs in undergraduate math. I suspect that's not what you intended: Of course we teach them natural language proofs first, which is what this post is about, right?

@LeeMosher Students should be able to systematically apply the basic rules of logic , to structure a proof and to make valid generalizations.

@LeeMosher: No, I do not agree with teaching natural language proofs first. I have decades of experience in teaching mathematics, and invariably all students who learn to use a deductive system permanently become capable of perfect logical reasoning (i.e. no more flawed thinking except careless mistakes), including the ability to check their own proofs with confidence, whereas most students who are unable to use a deductive system are also incapable of checking validity of their own proofs. After one becomes good at using a deductive system, one no longer needs to use it explicitly.

There are exceptions; 1% of students who never learnt any deduction system manage to acquire an unconscious grasp of sufficiently many logical reasoning rules covering all those needed for FOL, which hence makes them capable of constructing correct proofs and checking purported proofs. The only thing they would lack is the understanding that their logical reasoning is in fact sufficient for all mathematics. Unfortunately, many professors fall into this "exception" category but are unaware of it, so they incorrectly believe that students would be able to grasp what they unconsciously grasp.

By the way, I recommend against DC's proof checker. I have looked at it before and found that it is practically useless for actual mathematics and hardly helpful for mathematical pedagogy as well.

@user21820: Interesting. I do just fine teaching natural language proofs. I also think that many of my students will see only take a few proof based mathematical courses in their career, and I would rather sacrifice symbolic logic than mathematics.

@LeeMosher: What exactly do you mean "do just fine"? Have you ever attempted to measure your students actual grasp of valid mathematical reasoning, so as to compare before and after your teaching? If you are interested, I can provide you some test questions that require very little background mathematical knowledge but are likely to reveal any illogical reasoning.

@user21820 You wrote: "After one becomes good at using a deductive system, one no longer needs to use it explicitly." Exactly so! Although I am having fun stretching my proof checker to the limit, it was designed primarily to introduce students to the basic methods of proof and to be effectively discarded after a few weeks, like training wheels on a bicycle.

DC, I said very clearly that your system is hardly helpful for mathematical pedagogy, and I have given ample explanation in the past. I have no interest in repeating myself in vain.

@JW: Your question here asks about "tips for students". My answer is essentially "you need to change your teaching and then they automatically need no tips at all for checking proof validity". I'm only interested in teaching, so if you are interested in learning my recommended deductive system, then let me know and I can teach you in my chat-room.

@user21820 As I have said, there are many alternative proof-checkers available online. If you are not simply opposed in principle to their use, you should check them out. Maybe make a recommendation?

One tip is to have students think about whether their proof really uses all the hypotheses of the theorem. You can even put this in the question, e.g. "Part (b): where would your response to part (a) fail if $f_n$ only converged pointwise?"

This is at best misleading and at worse wrong. There are many problems that can be proven without using all the conditions stated. And just because you have used all the conditions implies nothing about the correctness of your 'proof'. This "tip" is simply a crutch that does not yield true understanding of mathematical proof.

(From a very basic point of view, the fact that not all conditions were used in the proof does not necessarily invalidate the proof; it could mean that what was proved is actually a broader statement. E.g. if you are asked to prove some $F(n)$ for positive integers $n$, but your proof does not use the fact that $n$ is positive, that does not by itself make the proof invalid; it is after all possible that you have actually proved $F(n)$ for all integers $n$.)

To other commenters, agree with the sentiment in general, but in the context of educating someone, this is a great tip, especially since the conditions in the question can be curated in such a way it should be used (at least initially). Once the students are familiar with this, then can start introducing questions where there are extra conditions that are not used in the proof, or immaterial to the result. After all, sometimes I discover flaws in my own proof by realizing that there is a factor that should affect my result, but it doesn't in my current proof, so I investigate.

@justhalf: You are conflating true understanding with heuristic crutches. Heuristics have their place, but not in the primary and most fundamental understanding of mathematical proof. Especially in pedagogy, where the extremely vast majority of students simply have not been taught properly what a genuine proof is, and hence they rely on their teachers to tell them whether they are correct or not. This poor pedagogy is so popular that it is considered acceptable. Really a pity.

@user21820 I do agree on the danger of what you call heuristic crutches, but in the big picture, despite its shortfall (some students taking the heuristics as the truth) in my opinion it is overall still a useful tool. Maybe not something that is applicable everywhere (if the students are in general faster in learning, can skip heuristics, e.g), but if it's to go through the mandatory classes that students are not interested in, I believe this is an acceptable compromise.

@justhalf: I totally agree that it is a useful tool. I use it all the time. But what I was trying to convey is that we (who already understand logical reasoning) must never present logical reasoning in a misleading manner to students (most of whom do not understand it). The primary and only criterion for logical reasoning is that one follows the deductive rules. The specific system does not matter, but it must be a fixed and precise one! Students need to understand that those rules suffice for all mathematical reasoning. (Most do not.) Heuristics are beneficial to them only after that.

@user21820 Deductive rules are the process, yes, but sometimes we may still miss something even while fully conforming to the rules. E.g., some proofs may require dividing into cases, and we may miss a case while doing the proof, while still following the deductive rules (sans the missed case). It doesn't mean the result is provably wrong, but it is incomplete. It may end up be wrong, or may just need small changes. These heuristics can act as a sanity check. In this case, we thought the logical reasoning is valid, but turns out we missed something that may be revealed by a sanity check.

@justhalf: Absolutely agreed. I will emphasize both of our points in my answer, since the asker requested me to post one.

Set an exercise with questions of the following form:

a) Read the proof below and identify the flaws in the proof.
...
b) Write a correct proof

Include as many questions in this style as you think appropriate so you can include several common types of errors, for example: not considering all cases. Depending on a fact that is false (the proof that there is no largest prime by assuming $p!+1$ is prime for example), incorrect use of converse (eg the use of if there is no change of sign, then there is no intersection), sign errors, incorrect generalisation instead of formal induction, use of a numerically calculated value instead of algebraically derived value ... you can probably think of plenty more.  Edexcel has resources for proofs at A-level standard that you can use.
Explain that the purpose of the exercise is to practice the skill of checking proofs and understand the expectations for proofs.
However, you should know that "proof" is an area that students find especially difficult.  Having marked iA-levels, the "proof" question was done correctly by about 1% of candidates, so don't expect this to be an easy process for students. This pons asinorum may be a bridge too far.

One thing that you should teach them is to "play the opponent's side". Normally the student (and even a professional mathematician writing an article) is in the mode of trying to convince the teacher and/or everybody else that his/her approach, computations, and logical argument make sense. In this mode mistakes are very hard to notice unless they are truly outrageous. In order to really catch the bugs, one should switch to the opposite mode of harsh criticism and reluctant acceptance of only the parts that are absolutely clear and foolproof.
The psychological trick is to imagine that the text was written by your worst enemy, whom you want to destroy at all costs, so if you cannot get at him directly, you should at least try your best to convince everyone that this particular work of his is total rubbish making no sense whatsoever. Then you start seeing awkward passages, unjustified leaps, and other things like that. Once you have marked them all with bright red pen and as negative comments as you can produce, you can switch to the proponent's side again and see how and if you can refute that criticism by changing and clarifying the corresponding places.
Usually it takes me 2-3 rounds of switching sides to make the text acceptable for showing to other people in the case of a medium length professional article. For short proofs like the ones we usually require students to produce 1 or 2 may be enough, but one is necessary under any circumstances. I'm in the profession for 30+ years and am considered a reasonably good writer and proofreader by many, but you will be amazed by what nonsense finds its way into my first drafts (if I ever show them to you, that is; the point is that I won't. :lol:).

There's two aspects of your question. How students check proofs and how to teach students how to check proofs.  Your question title is literally asking about the later (i.e. pedagogy), but from the text, you are more concerned with the former.
And I agree with this priority.  It's actually a more strong unknown.  (For once.)  Just making a clarifying comment.  And not to be pedantic or fussy at you.  But it's important to think about what the real question is to move forward, in issue analysis.
Quite often there is this confusion here about the method versus how to teach the method.  For an analogy, consider EVF (early vertical forearm) versus how to teach EVF, in freestyle swimming.  It actually takes more than just understanding exactly what EVF is to change one's stroke and start doing it.
On topic, my recommendation is to think about it from first principles, yourself.  And make some checklist for the student to use.  Note (to my critics) it's not about some mechanical checklist that will uncover every issue.  Even the act of using an IMPERFECT checklist, forces one to look at the problem again and allows the subconscious a chance to figure out the one little tail of yarn coming out of the ball...that will unwind it all.  For similar reasons, I used to make my technicians do a trip point and calibration check with malfunctioning electronic equipment.  It's not JUST that it might uncover something (even when they though the TP&CC was not germane...which often was a wrong assumption), BUT that it would slow them down a bit and allow the subconsious to engage.  A similar thing is the advice to rewrite the problem statement, when starting to answer...even totally clueless, it allows you to put something down and gives the subconsious a chance to engage.
I recommend to make your own list and adjust it over time (prioritize, etc.)  Here is mine.

Have we covered all the cases?

Domain and range issues?

Divided by zero kvetches.

Does each connection have a valid rationale (just mechanically looking at what you did!)


P.s.  I would not 100% expect that checking is the key issue.  In exam (or graded homework) situations, students may be trying to get partial credit and be well aware that their proof is flawed.  but a partial is better than a zero.  All that said, even in this case, the checking may help their subconscious to figure out how to fix their proof (that they know is flawed).

Thank you for bringing to the foreground the issue of method versus how to teach the method. I've edited the question body to include both aspects.

Personally I find it very disgusting to award more partial credit for a conceptually clearly bogus poof than for a blank answer. Students should be rewarded for a proper respect for truth, not for vomiting as much as possible in the hope that something sticks and earns points.

@user21820, and in these days of generative AI, I suppose the risk of a student randomly generating something in the hope that some or all of it is correct is greater than ever.

[...] That said, a genuine but flawed effort from a student who wants to learn but has not yet mastered the material and/or techniques deserves guidance in how to improve.

@JW: Genuine conceptual understanding should be rewarded even if incomplete. But nonsense should never be rewarded at all regardless of the intention. I don't penalize nonsense. But I reward students who do not make any serious conceptual errors.

On request from the asker, I will give my answer based on my decades of experience in teaching mathematics.
Frankly, anyone who is unable to check the validity of his/her own proof (excluding careless mistakes) simply does NOT understand what a genuine proof really is. Modern mathematics is based on FOL (first-order logic), and one must at least know a complete deductive system for FOL to be able to truly understand what a rigorous proof is. Informal proofs are nothing more than informal proofs. Once you know how to use a deductive system, it's trivial to check your own proof; just check that you are following the rules! I have personally taught using this foundational system.
I also do not agree with teaching natural language proofs first. This does not mean that one cannot use English words and phrasing in proofs. One can definitely do that. Technically the most important ingredients in a deductive system that is pedagogically beneficial are simply:

Fitch-style contexts: There are only two, the ⇒-subcontext and the ∀-subcontext. Not only is nothing else needed, but also the ability to produce a proof outline with the correct logical structure (which is entirely captured by these contexts) directly corresponds to the genuine understanding of rigorous proof. The usage of logical symbols does not matter, but any student who is incapable of producing the correct logical structure cannot have a proper understanding of proof validity. For example, proof by contradiction is totally obvious and undeniable once you understand Fitch-style contexts (and accept LEM for the relevant sentences), and proof by induction can only be properly understood (why it is sound and yet why it is an extra assumption) when one has a full grasp of logical structure.

Multiple sorts: A common mistake by many people is to teach just plain (one-sorted) FOL to students. Although many-sorted FOL can be reduced to one-sorted FOL, it is actually the superior form of FOL for logical reasoning. Think about it; "every human is an animal" directly translates to "∀x∈Humans ( x∈Animals )" where Humans and Animals are sorts, and it is actually a detour to express it in one-sorted FOL as "∀x ( Humans(x) ⇒ Animals(x) ). This is obvious in the syntactic symmetry between statements and their negations; the opposite of the above example is "∃x∈Humans ( ¬x∈Animals )". Worse still, insisting on unrestricted quantifiers will make it nasty or impractical for actual mathematics (e.g. the general recursion theorem is "∀A,S∈set ∀c∈A→S ∀f∈A×(ℕ×S)→S ∃g∈A×ℕ→S ∀x∈A ( g(x,0) = c(x) ∧ ∀k∈ℕ ( g(x,k+1) = f(x,(k,g(x,k))) ) )", which is clean like this in my system but would be humanly horrible to parse if forced to use one-sorted FOL).

Definitorial expansion: This is supported by actual proof assistants in some form or another, but is unfortunately not often taught to students, and so they simply do not understand the difference between definitorial expansion and ∃-elimination, which are the 2 ways of defining things in mathematics. Some people who might think that we can do away with definitorial expansion in a sufficiently strong set theory, but this is a horrible mistake in pedagogy. Not only would one have to go all the way to class functions in order to get the powerset operation from the powerset axiom, or cartesian product, or Ordinals, or countless other useful things that are not granted as inbuilt primitives, it is extremely misleading to invoke set theory when it is totally unnecessary. For example consider defining oddness over PA, which is a simple but instructive example demonstrating the need for precise teaching of definitorial expansion (i.e. what exactly are the rules governing how to define new predicate/function-symbols).


Again, let me emphasize that although I use symbols in my teaching, this is not necessary. I observe that in the long run the familiarity with logical symbols does make students competent in handling statements of arbitrarily high logical complexity, which is quite unattainable with natural language. However, if one does not have the time (a full semester) to properly learn FOL, then the next best approach is to use natural language phrases together with the above ingredients. For example the following is a valid rigorous proof that follows the above principles.
Define that k is odd iff there is some x∈ℤ such that k = x·2+1, for each k∈ℤ.  [definitorial expansion]
Given any k,m∈ℤ:  [∀-subcontext]
    If k is odd and m is odd:  [⇒-subcontext]
        Let x∈ℤ such that k = x·2+1.  [∃-elim]
        Let y∈ℤ such that m = y·2+1.  [∃-elim]
        k·m = (x·2+1)·(y·2+1)
         = (x·2+1)·(y·2)+(x·2+1)·1
         = ((x·2+1)·y)·2+(x·2+1)
         = ((x·2+1)·y)·2+x·2)+1
         = ((x·2+1)·y+x)·2+1.
        And (x·2+1)·y+x∈ℤ.
        Thus k·m is odd.
For any k,m∈ℤ, if k is odd and m is odd then k·m is odd.

Invariably all students who learn to use a deductive system permanently become capable of perfect logical reasoning (i.e. no more flawed thinking except careless mistakes), including the ability to check their own proofs with confidence, whereas most students who are unable to use a deductive system are also incapable of checking validity of their own proofs. After one becomes good at using a deductive system, one no longer needs to use it explicitly.
There are exceptions; 1% of students who never learnt any deduction system manage to acquire an unconscious grasp of sufficiently many logical reasoning rules covering all those needed for FOL, which hence makes them capable of constructing correct proofs and checking purported proofs. The only thing they would lack is the understanding that their logical reasoning is in fact sufficient for all mathematics. Unfortunately, many professors fall into this "exception" category but are unaware of it, so they incorrectly believe that students would be able to grasp what they unconsciously grasp.

What tips do you have for students to check the validity of their proofs, apart from showing them to a more experienced mathematician, and what approaches can we use to help them spot mistakes and errors, and then correct them?

So my answer is essentially that you need to change your teaching and then they automatically would not need any tips at all to be able to check proof validity.
Note that this does not invalidate the usefulness of heuristics in rapid guess-evaluation of proof validity. But the crucial point here is that the primary and only criterion for logical reasoning is that one follows the deductive rules. In addition, students need to understand that those rules suffice for all mathematical reasoning. (Most do not.) Heuristics are beneficial to them only after that. One useful heuristic is to check every condition of a theorem to see how it has been used (if at all) in a proof and to figure out whether it is actually required or not; if there is a counter-example without it then it must be used at least once in the proof. The deductive rules eliminate conceptual mistakes, but do not eliminate careless mistakes, so heuristics are useful to catch the latter. I just want to emphasize that heuristics must never be taught as a part of logical reasoning.
For additional related resources, take a look at this post about logical puzzles and games and this post about concrete interesting mathematics. You may also be interested in some other stuff linked from my profile page.

Can you recommend any  proof-checker(s)  to learn the basic methods of proof and get immediate validation of each line as it is entered?

"then they automatically would not need any tips at all to be able to check proof validity" the rest of your answer is good, but this part I think is more of an hyperbolic generalisation. Nobody never needs a tips. We all can learn from each other even if we are experts, for example, how to make sure we don't miss things, what steps can we do to reduce careless mistakes, how to think about certain things more efficiently (not about efficacy!), etc. We are not robots, we need tips :) Only robots can execute instructions perfectly consistently.

The perspective in this answer seems rather idiosyncratic. For instance, regarding the sentence "1% of students who never learnt any deduction system manage to acquire an unconscious grasp of [...]": To which base set does this 1% refer? From the beginning mathematics students I've seen, certainly many more than 1% are able to learn to apply valid logical reasoning without learning a formal deductive system. And the vast majority of those who are not, will most likely not be able to understand a formal deductive system either.

Since you're backing up your answer by saying that it is "based on my decades of experience in teaching mathematics" and since I know many other people with decades of experience of teaching in mathematics (I have only a bit more than one decade of experience myself) who will disagree with you, I think it is fair to ask you to provide some context: which kind of courses do you teach to which kind of students?

@JochenGlueck: I can teach well at all levels, from high-school to graduate level, and to all kinds of students, whether mathematics majors or not, and whether they have mathematical background knowledge or not. As for my point about the 1%, you are misinterpreting that point, because I mean that only 1% unconsciously acquire and adhere totally to sufficiently many logical reasoning rules covering all those needed for FOL. If a student also invokes illogical reasoning without being careless, he/she does not count. If a student can't do some FOL reasoning, he/she does not count either.

By the way, you are simply wrong about "vast majority of those who are not ... will most likely not be able to understand a formal deductive system". A typical human above the age of 12 can easily learn a deductive system for PL from a good teacher, and then can easily learn the rest of the rules for full FOL within the next year from the same teacher. It can be earlier if we have optimal pedagogy from young. If you don't believe me, just bring me any high-school student who wants to learn from me for a few hr per wk, and I will teach him/her FOL within 6 mth.

@user21820: "I can teach well at all levels," Well, "can" is hypothetical. How often and with how many and with which students have you actually done what you suggest here - i.e., taught them proofs by first teaching them a formal deductive system before teaching them natural language proofs.

@JochenGlueck: I do not lie unlike many other people. When I say "can" I mean it. I have done it, and that is why I know I have the ability to. And, yes, including to lay people who do not have any prior knowledge of proofs or contest mathematics. I also find your antagonistic attitude rather bad. You are free to disbelieve me, and continue your own ways of teaching. My students all benefit from my teaching and achieve 100% clear mathematical understanding, and I don't care if other teachers aren't interested in achieving the same.

@user21820: Actually, I did not claim (nor believe) that you are lying. It is a very common thing that happens, in my experience, to almost everybody (including myself) that one's beliefs about what one can and what one can't do change when one has to do things in different contexts than one is used to. This has nothing to do with lying. Please let me also note I do not consider my attitude as antagonistic. My perspective is as follows: You claim that one should do things in a way how I've hardly ever seen them done by anyone in practice and you claim that your approach is superior [...]

[...] to what most other people do. This is an extraordinary claim and thus requires extraordinary evidence. The sentence "I've done it, so I know that I can do it" does not seem like extraordinary evidence. But the issue isn't that I wouldn't believe you (on the contrary, I do believe you that you have done it and that you thus can do it). What I doubt is whether your experience is applicable to a variety of common teaching situations; so I asked for the context of your experience. Needless to add, you're obviously under no obligation to tell me, and it seems that you decided not to.

@JochenGlueck: Your earlier comments seemed to imply that you do not believe that I can in fact achieve what I stated with the general public. As I said 8 hr ago, I have taught FOL to lay people who do not have any prior knowledge of proofs or contest mathematics, without passing through natural language proofs, and in my opinion it yields superior understanding. I always test my students to the limit, to ensure that they actually do understand completely and not just "get by". Is that insufficient context? I also gave you a way to verify my method: bring me a willing student.

"Informal proofs are nothing more than informal proofs." I'm naturally curious what exactly you meant by this sentence before either agreeing with it or arguing against it. Understood literally, it is a tautology of the kind $X=X$, which is, of course, true, but rather devoid of interesting meanings, so I suspect that the intent was to convey something more profound than that :-)

@fedja: Indeed it's just a tautology. But you should know that a lot of people seem to believe that informal proofs are much more than that, such as people who claim that mathematics does not need formal proofs, or that mathematics is about intuition and formal proofs are not the real basis, or many other things. Even the asker here has a misconception of "proof", since he/she said "What tips do you have for students to check the validity of their proofs, apart from showing them to a more experienced mathematician ...", in which "proof" is conflated with "informal proof". [cont]

[cont] If you think about it, it's by definition obvious that checking the validity of a proof does not depend on "experience" unless it is not a genuine (rigorous) proof. This does not mean that informal proofs have no value, but each informal proof has to be completely backed by the existence of a formal proof or at least a confidence that a formal proof exists that follows the outline of the informal one. The very idea that a student cannot be fully confident of being able to check their own proofs (excluding careless mistakes) reveals the failure to teach FOL deduction. [cont]

[cont] An example of the fallacious conflation of "proof" with "informal proof" is the bogus proof by Kempe of the 4-colour theorem, which stood unchallenged for a decade. My point is that any student who is taught FOL properly would know that an informal 'proof' (e.g. Kempe's) has little value unless one firstly grasps that every mathematical proof must be formalizable in proper FOL and secondly convinces oneself (and others) that the informal proof is indeed formalizable in this manner (even if one does this only mentally). Without this, an informal 'proof' should not be called "proof".

OK, mostly agreed with this part then :-). One questionable point is about intuition versus formal proofs. IMHO, you need both: when I construct a long and tangled proof, I do not bother to check some steps on the first run and some of them may later fail, so I just replace them with different ones until the whole contraption loosely holds together, after which it is time to tighten the nuts and do the formal check. That second stage is indispensable, of course, but so is the first, unless you want to spend infinite time on verifying details before the whole scheme becomes clear. Cont'd

Also note, that many significant errors can be caught at that "first stage level". I often do not see immediately where the sign is flipped or a factor of 2 is lost in a long argument, but I can see immediately that the end doesn't match the beginning just because it doesn't. Then, again, of course, I have to go through the painstaking task of finding the exact place that fails, but you shouldn't underrate the usefulness of the "general feeling of the logical flow" (for the lack of a better word) that is not immediately formalizable and does come with experience, indeed.

@fedja: I agree completely. I didn't say we don't need intuition, and it is arguably nearly as indispensable as the formal proof. It's just that somehow strangely many people think that it has higher importance than (belief in existence of) formal proof. I would also say that although "general feeling of logical flow" is not formalizable per se, it's arguably only obtainable after having a mastery of logic.
